# Why is the output of the CPP code failing for "832564823476" as input?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I am currently enrolled for the Data Structures and Algorithm Specialization on Coursera. I came across a problem as my assignment. The problem tells to find the last (unit) digit of the sum of n-terms of a fibonacci sequence.

For ex: 
Input : 3  
Output : 4 
F0 + F1 + F2 + F3 = 0 + 1 + 1 + 2 = 4

The soltuion for this I provided was :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int lastDigit=0;
int fibLastDigit(unsigned long long);

int main() {
    unsigned long long terms;
    cin>>terms;         //0<=n<=10^18
    cout<<fibLastDigit(terms);
    return 0;
}

int fibLastDigit(unsigned long long nTh) { 
    int first=0, second=1, third;
    if(nTh == 0) {
        lastDigit = first;
        return lastDigit;
    }
    else if(nTh == 1) {
        lastDigit = second;
        return lastDigit;
    }
    else if(nTh > 1) { 
        lastDigit = 1;
        while(nTh>=2) {
            first = first % 10;
            second = second % 10;
            third = ((first + second)%10);
            first = second;
            second = third;
            lastDigit = (lastDigit + third) % 10;
            nTh--;

        }

    }
    return lastDigit;
}
```

But the code fails for 832564823476. The console freezes and doesn't provide any output.

Comment: It's going to take a long time for your computer to count down from that number, one by one. Even on modern CPUs. Because that's what you told your computer to do, decrement it, one by one. You must realize that this is going to take a while, so maybe you should've tried running this on a quantum computer?

Comment: You are counting down from 832564823476. Yikes. Debugging Pro Tip: try a smaller number to see if the algo works.

Comment: Even if that whole loop would only take a single cycle, it would take a 2.4 GHz machine almost 6 minutes to execute this.

Comment: @nicomp Yup, this works for a smaller number.

Comment: If you look at the last digit of enough Fibonacci numbers, you will discover that there's a cycle. (If you think about it, you might realise that there must be one.) It's also not a very long cycle.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the first `n` Fibonacci numbers `F(n)` is `F(n+2)-1` ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Combinatorial_identities)). You are interested in the last digit of this number.

Now consider that the last digit of `F(n)` only depends on the last digits of `F(n-1)` and `F(n-2)`. There are at most 100 possible such pairs, so the series of last digits has to repeat eventually. Indeed, `lastDigitOf(F(n)) = lastDigitOf(F(n+60))` (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113536/fibonaccis-final-digits-cycle-every-60-numbers)), so you should be able to find an algorithm that is *much* faster than what you have right now. Then you won't have your console "freezing" (i.e. waiting for your algorithm to complete) any longer.